# How to use jQuery to return value of "form" from select in Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I need jQuery to pass through the value of the form attribute from the select tag.  At this point, I cannot figure out how to obtain that value.

Within simple_form_for, the input statement is:

```
<%= f.input(:year_id, {input_html: {form: 'new_car'}, collection: Year.all.collect { |c| [c.year, c.id] }, prompt: "Year?"}) %>
```

This transforms to the following HTML select:

```
<select name="car[year_id]" id="car_year_id" form="new_car" class="select optional"><option value="">Year?</option>
<option value="1">2000</option>
<option value="2">2001</option>
<option value="3">2002</option>
<option value="4">2003</option>
<option value="5">2004</option>
<option value="6">2005</option>
<option value="7">2006</option>
<option value="8">2007</option>
<option value="9">2008</option>
<option value="10">2009</option>
<option value="11">2010</option>
<option value="12">2011</option>
<option value="13">2012</option>
<option value="14">2013</option></select>
```

Within jQuery, I can obtain the selected value using:

```
var year = $('select#car_year_id :selected').val();
```

What I need to do is to obtain the value of form: so that I can pass it to the car controller, much like I obtain the value of year.  Any searches I do simply discuss using AJAX in forms, which doesn't help.  I have tried a series of permutations of the var statement, for the most part only getting the value of "undefined" for form:.  Since I am a JavaScript/jQuery noob, I'm not even certain I am looking at this right...  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question is:

```
var form = $('select#car_year_id').attr("form");
```